# Are there constants for iOS notifications in MonoTouch? And how to get a "local" observer?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Im currently trying to figure out which notification string is sent if the app gets pushed to background. Is there an enumerator in MT I keep on overseeing or do I really have to use strings as shown in this example:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ( "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification", MyNotification);
```

If there are no constants: where can I find the valid strings? Which one do I need for my "pushed to background" notification?

The other thing: is there a way to make a specific controller observer a notification? In my example I want to get rid of the popover controller a controller is currently showing. So I would like that MY controller observers the notifcation instead of having the global approach as shown above.
The problem is: if I do it like above in my view controller, remove the view controller and show a different one, the removed one still gets the notification. This means I don't get rid of the reference to that controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are constants. You can find them as static properties on the class that the notification refers to. For instance, to receive a notification when the app moves to the background, you could do something like this:

```
NSObject enterBackgroundObserver;
//...
enterBackgroundObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (UIApplication.DidEnterBackgroundNotification,
    delegate(NSNotification ntf) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Entered background!");
});
```

Don't forget to remove the observer when you no longer need it:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (enterBackgroundObserver);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure is. I believe this is what you want. `UIApplicationState.Active`

As in

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
{
    if(application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
    {
        // this means your app is currently in the foreground
    }
    else
    {
        // this means a notification came in when your app was in the background.
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you overriding this method? UIViewController does not provide ReceivedRemoteNotification().

Comment: This would be in your Main.cs, AppDelegate class. UIViewController is not responsible for handling notifications directly.

Comment: this method is for receiving remote notifications. It will not be called when the application moves from/to foreground/background. Your code only checks if the app is in the background or foreground when a remote notification is received.